# Is this a tomato plant?

Tags: identification, tomatoes

I personally never grow tomatoes. I'm collecting some seedlings that grow wildly from tomatoes that people throwed outside. I couldn't figure out whether that small plant on the right is a tomato or not?

[image]

[image]

The plant on the left side I'm sure it is.

Comment: It might be. Sometimes tomato plants don't show the mature "lobed" leaflet shape on the first few leaves for some reason.

Comment: Yes. Probably the shape is kinda deformed. I might need to wait for several weeks to really know it.

Comment: Does it smell like a tomato? If you rub a leaf and smell your fingers it should smell like a tomato plant if it is one.

Comment: It does not look like a tomato to me. To smooth for a start. Does it have a lot of fine hairs on the stems ? (Tomato's do)

Comment: @davidgo, man you're right. I've just realized that. 'm sure I've been picking up the wrong plants and there so many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main things, based on which you will be able to recognize a young tomato plant:

1) The stem
It has a little strings like hair all over it, which are basically potential roots. When they meet dirt, they become ones. Every tomato plant should have them. 
[image: Young tomato plant stamp fuzz]

2) The leaves.
In order to recognize whether they are from tomato, you have to see the picture above. As every plant, they are typisch and special. [image: Typical tomato plant leaves]

I can not see the stem very well on your picture, but based on the leaves, it doesnt look to me as a tomato plant personally.